# Error; bookmark in PDF

Tags: hyperref, counters, bookmarks

I have this problem in LaTeX when I use;

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Resumen}

\section*{\bf Agradecimientos} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Agradecimientos}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabla de Contenidos}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabla de Contenidos}

.
.
.

\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}

\section*{Capítulo 1 Introducción}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Capitulo 1 Introducción}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\subsection{Origen y necesidades del tema}
```

[image: error; bookmark in PDF]

How can I fix this?
Thanks for all!

Comment: What is the problem you want fixed?

Comment: In the left side, the index is not well like in the right side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{bookmark}`. It implements a more robust algorithm with duplicate anchors and broken section structure. Maybe it is able to fix some of the issues.

But it cannot correct the LaTeX code:

- Setting `\tableofcontents` twice does not make sense.
- The entry for the table of contents in the table of contents is put *after*
  the table of contents. The page number will be wrong, if the table of contents is more than one page.
- `\section*{Capítulo 1 Introducción}`

  - Using `\section`\ for chpaters.
  - Manual numbering.
- `\setcounter{page}{1}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}`
  can be replaced by `\pagenumbering{arabic}` or depending on the class `\mainmatter` can be used.
- LaTeX2e deprecates the use of old font switches `\bf` and friends.
  The new form are `\bfseries` as font switch statement and the argument form `\textbf{...}`. Anyway `\section` titles are usually already bold.